# Untracked git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

For one of my project I decided to use submodules.
They are nice to keep different plugins for application in separate repos, but I have one issue.
Any time I have uncommited changes in the submodule I cannot do anything with the main repo, it keeps track of the submodule and the moment I try to do a commit or anything I have to choose between loosing all my submodule changes or commit them first.

Its a huge pain to work on the main repo because the submodules getting in the way all the time. I have lost changes in the submodule so many times due to main repo deleting them when I was stashing or changing anything in the main repo.

So my question is, is there a way to tell git to only clone a subrepository but completely ignore it afterwards?

Comment: are you using the command line git client, or some gui tool? I don't _currently_ use submodules but have used them quite a lot in the past and don't remember this sort of issue.

Comment: I am using gitkraken.

Comment: looks like this is gitkraken "feature" and there is also feature request to be able to disable this behaviour https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/193513/option-to-disable-submodule-synchronization , but this is still not implemented.

Comment: Command-line Git is less destructive than it sounds like gitkraken is here, but submodules are generally a pain in the <insert anatomy part> like this. Still, you might want to learn the CLI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to choose between loosing all my submodule changes or commit them first.

You should be able to add and commit, while ignoring your submodules:

> ### [`submodule.<name>.ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submoduleltnamegtignore)

> Defines under what circumstances "`git status`" and the `diff` family show a submodule as modified.
> When set to "`all`", it will never be considered modified (but it will nonetheless show up in the output of status and commit when it has been staged).

Comment: Looks like it works for vanilla git, but not for gitkraken. Well, kinda. I can stash using git and unstash using gitkraken. I can also stash using gitkraken and unstash using git. Now it only causes issues when I both stash and unstash using gitkraken. I guess its a bug in gitkraken.

Comment: Also for anyone having the same issue. You put the config line in your `.git/config` file under `[submodule "<name>"]` as `ignore = all`. Setting `submodule.<name>.ignore = all` under `[core]` will not work.

Comment: @HubertNNN a `git config submodule.<name>.ignore all` should work and generate the same syntax you mention in `.git/config`.